# Azure common alert schema sets the commonPropertie as "null"

Tags: json, azure, schema, azure-logic-apps, azure-alerts

Well I will explain all about my case.

Im trying to set up Azure alerts that sends a custom mails, to do so I need a logic app that parse the info about the said alerts.

The problem is, even if I enable the common alert schema, and fill the custom properties field, as you can [see in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFVuk.png).
But what this alert sends to my Logic App in the customProerties field is a [Null value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7gxp.png), I don't get why.

But more than that, if I disable the common alert schema, the custom properties field will be sent without problems.
I don't understand if common alert schema doesn't allow customProperties, or if Im doing something bad, I need help.

Thanks for read and ask for it if anything of this post is bad explained.

Comment: Did you get to the bottom of this by any chance? It looks like this only happens on the Activity Log alert rules?

Answer (score 1):

I have just confirmed this issue with Microsoft support.

If I point an Activity Log Alert Rule to an Action Group Webhook with Common Schema enabled then the Custom Properties don't appear in the JSON payload. If I disable the Common Schema then the property does appear in the payload.

If I do the same for a Metric alert or Log Query alert, the Custom Properties do appear at the Webhook endpoint regardless of whether the Common Schema is enabled or not.

Microsoft pointed that the schemas for each type [are documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/alerts-common-schema) (no custom property on the Activity Log Common Schema) and that this is not a bug. Well... the Alert Rule form does allow to configure the Custom Properties for each type of alert so... ah well, nevermind.

They also said "There are plans to align the behaviour on all alert types including activity logs, although there is no definite ETA though. For now, the best option for you to be able to customize the payloads of activity log alerts is by using logic app as an action group."